# PowerShell - Convert CSV to XLSX

Tags: powershell

I found this script on here, please help me understand this better.

1. What is the whole "gps" part of the script for?
2. What part of this script is overwriting my original CSV and copying in the PC's taskmanager list?  Processes.
3. What does this do, why 51?  ($xlOut,51)

I went searching for "New-Object -com" and really couldn't locate what I thought I would find...  Doesn't explain what the -com does or provide a list of paramaters along with -com.  All I found was -comObject.

```
(gps excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).count
$csvpath="C:\path\to\file.csv"
gps | Export-Csv $csvpath -NoTypeInformation
$xl=New-Object -com "Excel.Application" 
$wb=$xl.workbooks.open($csvpath)
$xlout=$csvpath.Replace('.csv','.xlsx') 
$wb.SaveAs($xlOut,51) 
$xl.Quit()
(gps excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).count
```

Comment: Well I see GPS is an alias for the Get-Process cmdlet...  This is starting to make me think its what is overwriting my CSV files with process information from taskman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What is the whole "gps" part of the script for?**

The two `(gps excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).count` lines at the start and end of the script count the number of Excel executables running. `gps` is the shorthand alias for `get-process`. You can find out more by doing `help gps` which returns:

> NAME
>       Get-Process
>
> SYNOPSIS
>       Gets the processes that are running on the local computer or a remote computer.

Those two lines serve no other purpose than to count the number Excel processes running and output the value to the console. They don't affect the rest of the script and would appear to be some sort of sanity check for the original author of the script.

> **What part of this script is overwriting my original CSV and copying in the PC's taskmanager list? Processes.**

The next part:

```
$csvpath="C:\path\to\file.csv"
gps | Export-Csv $csvpath -NoTypeInformation
```

This gets the list of all running processes and exports as a CSV file to `$csvpath`. This will overwrite the file at `$csvpath` every time it runs.

The `$xl=New-Object -com "Excel.Application"` line tells PowerShell to launch an instance of `Excel.Application`. Because Excel is a COM object (or more accurately a COM automation server running in its own process) the `-com` switch tells PowerShell what its ProgID is. If you didn't have the `-com` (or to give it its full name `ComObject`) switch then PowerShell would go off hunting for a managed (.NET) type to instantiate.

> **What does this do, why 51? ($xlOut,51)**

The lines:

```
$xlout=$csvpath.Replace('.csv','.xlsx')
```

replaces the `.csv` extension in `$csvpath` with `.xlsx` thus generating a new file name `C:\path\to\file.xlsx`

```
$wb.SaveAs($xlOut,51)
```

This tells Excel to save your workbook in the file `$xlout`. The `51` parameter would normally be a value from an enumerated type. In this case it comes from the `XlFileFormat` enumeration, specifically `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.

Comment: Even better explanation.  Good detail.  This site is my new favorite for answers.

Answer (score 3):

> *1. What is the whole "gps" part of the script for?*

```
PS C:\> Get-Alias -Name gps

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           gps -> Get-Process
```

> *2. What part of this script is overwriting my original CSV and copying in the PC's taskmanager list? Processes.*

This statement:

```
gps | Export-Csv $csvpath -NoTypeInformation
```

> *3. What does this do, why 51? ($xlOut,51)*

51 is the numeric value of the `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` [file type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff198017.aspx) that's passed as the second parameter of the [`SaveAs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff841185.aspx) method (so the workbook is saved in the correct format).

---

As for `-COM`: that's short for the parameter `-ComObject`. `New-Object` by default creates .net objects, but Office applications must be instantiated as COM objects, so the extra parameter is required.

Comment: Thank you sir, very informative answer.  My script is working great now and I have an understanding of why.  As of this post, my reputation isn't high enough to hit the "^" button to mark answer as useful or I would.